# ODBC fails after changing pc date

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, system-clock

We have a girl here who runs a report successfully, then changes the date on her pc, then tries the report again and gets a Connection failed error.

- The report is ran in MS Access 2003
- The ODBC itself uses Windows Authentication
- The linked table uses a UID different than her Windows login
- The error when running the report: SQLState '28000' SQL Server Error: 18452 "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection."
- Error received when testing the ODBC: SQLState '08004' SQL Server Error: 4060 "Server rejected the connection; Access to selected database has been denied."
- The SQL Log had this error: "SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. [CLIENT: ##.##.##.##]"
- I am able to recreate the failure on my machine.

I'm thinking it's something between the Windows Authentication/Active Directory/ODBC but I'm not very experienced in the first 2.

And yes, I know this isn't an ideal situation. This will all be converted to C#.NET at some point.

TIA for any ideas.

Comment: What is she setting the date to? And why?

Comment: Active Directory gets really cranky if the PC's clock isn't at least *close* to the DC's. They don't have to be in perfect sync, but if you're changing the *date* on the PC (not the time), you're going to have problems.

Comment: She's changing the date to the last day of the previous month. Why? Because the legacy system (10+ years old) requires it? She has been able to do it this way for years and within the last few months, she has seen this problem.

Comment: Give her a second computer to use with the legacy system, or tell her to exit Access while she's using it. Converting to a C# application isn't necessarily going to fix the problem here, if it's still going to use ODBC.

Comment: We're going to do a workaround to make it work. I've never seen someone needing to back date their computer. I'm attempting to check for any AD/DC changes within a month before her issue appeared. That has to be it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Here's another little wrinkle... All of this was happening on a Window 7 32 bit machine. When I tested it on an XP machine, there were no problems. What does that mean?